# Why does not work two controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have controller is named `"UserController"` in top of page:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController"><input type="text" ng-model="search"></div>
```

Also the same controller in bottom page from directive `ng-view`:

```
<div class="bottom" ng-controller="UserController">{{search}}</div>
```

Why I dont get value `{{search}}` in bottom part, when I fill field input in top?

Comment: do you have a `$scope.search` variable?

Comment: Because each div has its own $scope, and is controlled by its own UserController instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Can I use one controller two times in a page?**

Yes, you can use two controllers in AngularJs, [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8oBs17eaJGaDvoQGwOzC?p=preview) is a demo.

> **What happens when I use ng-controller?**

When you add ng-controller to a DOM element, angular create an instance of controller function and attaches it with that DOM, and thats why there is no two way data-binding between those divs.

> **How can I use data binding to share data between controllers?**

You can use `$rootScope` variable or you can use services.

you can create service and inject in controller as dependency, so you can access its property with two way binding feature.

Comment: I updated it, please check, it is just an example that you can use same controller twice, but there will not be two way databinding.

Comment: problem is that I use `ng-view` which loads HTML with controller

Comment: @Kaffarov You can check the link now, I updated it as ng-view, it also supports but each controller instance will have different memory scope and there will not two way databinding.

Comment: If you want databinding, then you can use rootScope or service or factory as I mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said by JB Nizet, you need to have everything in the same "div".

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <div id="search-query">{{search}}</div>
</div>
```

Having the `search-query` at the bottom of the page is a matter of CSS, not Angular.

Comment: For what `id="search-query"`?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are not singletons.  You have one controller for the top div, a second controller for the second div.  One scope for the top div, one scope for the bottom div.

Both controllers have the same name, but you are ultimatally calling you controller function twice.

Some options you might want to consider to solve your problem:

**Option 1) Use parent scope.**

```
ng-model="$parent.search"
{{$parent.search}}
```

**Option 2) Use root scope.**

```
ng-model="$root.search"
{{$root.search}}
```

**Option 3) Store the value in a service.**

Services are singletons.  If you type `myService.search = $scope.search`, then that value can read from the other controller.
You wont be able to watch a service variable, so perhaps you want to use the observer pattern here.

```
app.service("search", function() {
    var listerners = [];
    this.register = function(listener) {
        listerners.push(listener);
    };
    this.update = function(searchValue) {
        for(var i in listerners) {
            listerners[i](searchValue);
        }
    };
});

app.controller("UserController", function($timeout, search){
    search.register(function(searchValue) {
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.search = searchValue;
        });
    });
    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        search.update(newVal);
    });
});
```

**Option 4) Broadcast the new value.**

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('search', newVal);
});
$scope.$on('search', function(event, data) {
    $scope.search = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple instances of the same controller in your page. They share the same functionality. But every instance of that controller is getting his own $scope. So in your first controller $scope.search can be 'mySearch', but the second controller won't get this, because it's another $scope.

You can do two things:
You can put the controller on a containing element, let's say the body, so both your input and your div are within the same $scope.

OR, if you want them to be seperate, you can use a service to share the search.

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.mySearch"/>
    </div>      
    <div ng-controller="UserController">
         {{search.mySearch}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Your Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function(){
  return { mySearch: '' };
});

myApp.controller('UserController', function( $scope, Data ){
  $scope.search = Data;
});
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/668/)